# Get edited data in webforms to vb.net code

Tags: vb.net

Will this code work to move edited data in webforms to vb.net code and assign to control.

I want to autosave webforms data in vb.net using jQuery javascript

```
Partial Class AccountSummary
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    <WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Sub SaveData(editedFields As Object)
        Try
            ' Deserialize the JSON data
            Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim editedFieldsDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = serializer.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(editedFields.ToString())

            ' Update controls on the server side using only edited fields
            For Each keyValuePair In editedFieldsDictionary
                Dim controlId As String = keyValuePair.Key
                Dim controlValue As Object = keyValuePair.Value

                ' Find the control by ID
                Dim control As Control = FindControlRecursive(Page, controlId)

                If control IsNot Nothing Then
                    ' Update the control value based on the type
                    If TypeOf control Is TextBox Then
                        DirectCast(control, TextBox).Text = controlValue.ToString()
                    ElseIf TypeOf control Is CheckBox Then
                        DirectCast(control, CheckBox).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(controlValue)
                    ElseIf TypeOf control Is DropDownList Then
                        DirectCast(control, DropDownList).SelectedValue = controlValue.ToString()
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Handle exception
        End Try
    End Sub

    ' Recursive method to find a control by ID
    Private Shared Function FindControlRecursive(parent As Control, controlId As String) As Control
        For Each child As Control In parent.Controls
            If child.ID = controlId Then
                Return child
            End If

            Dim foundControl As Control = FindControlRecursive(child, controlId)
            If foundControl IsNot Nothing Then
                Return foundControl
            End If
        Next

        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: A web method is only a chunk of code, and is a end point. That web method thus cannot see nor modify controls on the current web page, since the web page not been posted back to the server. So, code behind can't modify such controls unless the page been posted back to the server. But then again, if you post the page back, then you not needing or using ajax + JavaScript anymore, and you don't need as such.  So, a server side web method cannot update controls on a page - the client side JavaScript has to modify the controls.

Answer (score -1):

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Json
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Partial Class AccountSummary
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    
    Public Shared Sub SaveData(editedFields As Object)
        Try
            
            Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim editedFieldsDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = serializer.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(editedFields.ToString())

            
            For Each keyValuePair In editedFieldsDictionary
                Dim controlId As String = keyValuePair.Key
                Dim controlValue As Object = keyValuePair.Value

                
                Dim control As Control = FindControlRecursive(Page, controlId)

                If control IsNot Nothing Then
                    
                    If TypeOf control Is TextBox Then
                        DirectCast(control, TextBox).Text = controlValue.ToString()
                    ElseIf TypeOf control Is CheckBox Then
                        DirectCast(control, CheckBox).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(controlValue)
                    ElseIf TypeOf control Is DropDownList Then
                        DirectCast(control, DropDownList).SelectedValue = controlValue.ToString()
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            
        End Try
    End Sub

    
    Private Shared Function FindControlRecursive(parent As Control, controlId As String) As Control
        For Each child As Control In parent.Controls
            If child.ID = controlId Then
                Return child
            End If

            Dim foundControl As Control = FindControlRecursive(child, controlId)
            If foundControl IsNot Nothing Then
                Return foundControl
            End If
        Next

        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Partial Public Class YourPage
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' Check if it's a postback to avoid adding the attributes on every page load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' Get the existing onclick attribute if any
        Dim existingOnclick As String = btnBack.Attributes("onclick")

        ' Construct the new onclick attribute, calling your server-side method first and then the existing onclick
        Dim newOnclick As String = "return yourServerMethod();" ' 'return' is added to prevent the default behavior if needed
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(existingOnclick) Then
            newOnclick += existingOnclick
        End If

        ' Set the new onclick attribute
        btnBack.Attributes.Add("onclick", newOnclick)
    End If
End Sub

<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function YourServerMethod() As String
    ' Your server-side logic here
    ' This method will be called before any existing onclick event of the button
    ' You can perform any necessary actions

    Return "Server method executed successfully."
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).